# Why is this intuitive method valid?

Tags: probability, intuition

**Problem**. There are $2$ *white* and $3$ *black* balls in the urn. A person randomly picked $2$ balls and put $1$ *white* ball. What is the probability of the event that the next randomly-picked ball would be *white*.

To solve this problem formally you have to consider conditional probabilities and so on. But in the childhood I did not know such words so I was solving problems of this type in the following way.

---

**Intuitive solution**. Let's grind balls into powder and mix it. We will have $5$ (whatever you want, for instance) kilograms of powder. $\frac{2}{5}$ of each kilogram is *white* and $\frac{3}{5}$ is *black*. A person randomly took $2$ balls in my model means that he took $2$ kilogram of powder. Putting $1$ white ball means that he put $1$ kilogram of *white* powder.

After all actions there are $\left(5 \cdot\frac35-2\cdot \frac35\right)=\frac95$ kilograms of *black* powder and $\left(5 \cdot\frac25-2\cdot \frac25\right) + 1=\frac95=\frac{11}5$ kilograms of *white* powder. So the final probability of picking *white* ball is $\frac{11}{5}/\left(\frac{11}{5}+\frac{9}{5}\right) = \frac{11}{20}$.

---

You can check that this is the right answer, but the question is **why is this intuitive method valid?**

Comment: i can't understand your reasoning behind $3\cdot\frac35$ and $1+3\cdot\frac25$

Comment: Is it clear now, @ADG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grinding balls into powder is mathematically the same as calculating [expected value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value).

In fact, the reason why mathematicians often speak of expected value calculations as the sum of the possible values, *weighted* by their probabilities, is exactly why your intuition of *weights* of grinded balls is relevant.

---

The expected number of black balls taken out, $b$, is

$$E(b) = P(b=0)\cdot 0 + P(b=1) \cdot 1 + P(b=2) \cdot 2$$

The $P(b=k)$ for $k=0,1,2$ are

$$P(b=0) = \frac{1}{\binom{5}{2}} = \frac{1}{10}$$

$$P(b=1) = \frac{2 \cdot 3}{\binom{5}{2}} = \frac{3}{5}$$

$$P(b=2) = \frac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{5}{2}} = \frac{3}{10}$$

This gives us

$$E(b) = 0 + \frac{3}{5} + 2 \cdot \frac{3}{10} = \frac{6}{5}$$

This means that the expected number of black balls left after two are taken out is

$$3-E(b) = \frac{9}{5}$$

Similarly, the expected number of white balls taken out, $w$, is

$$E(w) = \frac{4}{5}$$

And the expected number of white balls remaining:

$$2-E(w) = \frac{6}{5}$$

You can calculate this directly, or notice that $$(3-E(b)) + (2-E(w)) = 5-E(b+w) = 5-2 = 3$$

---

After adding one white ball, the new expected number of white balls is

$$1+(2-E(w)) = 1 + \frac{6}{5} = \frac{11}{5}$$

There is now a total of $4$ balls, so the probability of choosing a white ball is

$$\frac{\frac{11}{5}}{4} = \frac{11}{20}$$